# How do I make IntelliJ leave this comment in the same line

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Java class defined like this:

```
@Data // Some explanation for @Data
@Entity
public class Blah {
}
```

When I apply automatic formatting, it changes it to this:

```
@Data
// Some explanation for @Data
@Entity
public class Blah {
}
```

Any idea which of the gazillion options it has for Java code style is the one that would leave that comment in the line it was? I cannot find it.

Comment: That's strange. Doesn't happen in my (quite old though) IDEA v.14.x.x. Which one do you use?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style.html

Answer (score 2):

A search of settings confirms that there is no option for "comments" on the "Wrapping and Braces" tab in Code Styles.

One possibility... I'm not sure if you simplified your example, but if you have a long comment that exceeds the right margin -- *Editor > Code Style (Root node)* "Right Margin (columns)" -- it will move it to the next line. That's the only thing I can think of. The "Ensure right margin is not exceeded" option determines if a *single* statement is broken up into multiple lines. But it does *not* affect a second expression (like your comment) from being moved to the next line. One way to confirm that this is indeed is what is happening is to change your comment to a `/* */` block comment. Then do the reformat. If only part of the comment is moved to the next line, that's the issue. If so, your options are to 1) suppress the formatting for a portion of your code. See *Editor > Code Style (Root node)* "Enable formatter markers in comments" 2) widen your right margin 3) open a feature request to not wrap end of line comments.

Comment: Yes, I simplified the example, and you are right, it's because the comment is too long.